# asymptotic normality and central limit theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Here's the question

Can somebody explain the difference between asymptotic normality and central limit theorem? 
They seem very similar to me.

Comment: Asymptotic normality is a property, while the CLT as its name suggests is a theorem. This theorem tells us that certain s.v. with certain conditions are asymptotically normally distributed. So it proves that certain s.v. have this asymptotic normality property.

Comment: what does s.v. mean?

Comment: sorry, stochastic variable

Answer (score 6):

*Asymptotic normality* is a feature of a sequence of probability distributions. We say that a sequence of probability distributions is asymptotically normal if 
it converges weakly to the normal distribution.

Asymptotic normality and the central limit theorem are closely related notions.

The *central limit theorem* gives an example of a sequence that is asymptotically normal. It establishes that probability distributions corresponding to the sequence of random variables
$$
Y_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_n,
$$
where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid random variables with $\operatorname EX=0$ and $\operatorname EX^2=1$, converges weakly to the standard normal distribution. The sequence of probability distributions of $Y_n$ is asymptotically normal.

The term *asymptotic normality* is usually used in statistics to describe asymptotic properties of an estimator.

Wikipedia has some nice pages about these topics (see [Asymptotic distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_distribution)
 and [Central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)
).